# Is pSQL and bqSQL are PHP predefined functions?

Tags: php, function, prestashop, psql

I'm currently developing a framework based on prestashop code. I found `pSQL` and `bqSQL` functions in DbQuery.php when they did queries such join tables, etc.

I'm trying to found the function on prestashop. But I didn't find any. I wondered if it is predefined functions from PHP? I looked from Google but there are no documentation (other than it might postgreSQL, but I'm not sure).

If anyone can tell me what are those functions for? Are there any difference?

Answer (score 10):

`pSQL` & `bqSQL` are **NOT** predefined functions from PHP. They are Prestashop functions from file **/config/alias.php**

Answer (score 2):

Currently named as "db::escape(...)" and defined as  "pSQL" in alias (as Happy said), in old 1.2 versions it was directly defined on db class.

Current method "escape" (PS 1.6)

```
public function escape($string, $html_ok = false, $bq_sql = false)
{
    if (_PS_MAGIC_QUOTES_GPC_)
        $string = stripslashes($string);
    if (!is_numeric($string))
    {
        $string = $this->_escape($string);
        if (!$html_ok)
            $string = strip_tags(Tools::nl2br($string));
        if ($bq_sql === true)
            $string = str_replace('`', '\`', $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Please note that "escape" method calls an "_escape" method from descendant class, that allows to implement a different protection on each database implementation).